# SimpleJSON returns null when handling a call from Postmen

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, postman, simplejson, http-accept-encoding

I've installed into my unity SimpleJSON in attempt to deserialize the received call from REST-HTTP call that hold a JSON

[simpleJSON](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON?fbclid=IwAR0SNtZgkeUjUvgHkIwmkE5tvNyP2Ln_NQX4ScDOCILjJUFZmmAyAN56c2o)

[that's my script](https://pastebin.com/Ucje2hcX?fbclid=IwAR0msT_nJ53r64yBu454qn0vNzS8Ce-0vRW_zkJuqXmMB1eFrHcl1mKulPU)

im listening to localhost 3000 and sending from postman

```
GET  HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3a64322b-a33c-4828-8347-11cdc7da70af
{
    "item": "seeds",
    "Answers": "5",
    "richText": "*some text*"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

when Simplejson received the data, I verified that the [raw data has arrived successfully](https://pastebin.com/rMAX9AvW?fbclid=IwAR2KUChQCUw9iz57x5vdQlPOCV86m6BQ_0MVEWx_bddBGNpVUoOZo30iUBk)

however, the proccess dumps an error when engaging the token '3000accept-encoding' (3000 is port number)
in line 529.

```
ctx.Add(TokenName, ParseElement(Token.ToString(), TokenIsQuoted));
```

since its a static function, i duplicated it and created an object returning version which returned all the data i could think of for debugging:
i, aJSON[i], Token, Token.Length, TokenName,TokenIsQuoted
and changed the line into

```
string final = "";
```

...

```
case ',':

   if (QuoteMode)
   {
      Token.Append(aJSON[i]);
      break;
   }
   final =  "aJSON[i] "+aJSON[i] +", token "+ Token + ", length "+ Token.Length +", token Name '" + TokenName+"', IsQuoted " + TokenIsQuoted+"-";
   if (Token.Length > 0 || TokenIsQuoted)
   {   
      try
      {
         ctx.Add(TokenName, ParseElement(Token.ToString(), TokenIsQuoted));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         final+="      "+e;
         return final;
      }
   }
```

what returned was:

```
aJSON[i] ,, token gzip, length 4, token Name '3000accept-encoding', IsQuoted False-      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at SimpleJSON.JSONNode.ParseTester (System.String aJSON) [0x00316] in C:\++Projects\SparkBeyond\Unity\Unity Projects\JSONDeserialize\Assets\SimpleJSON-master\SimpleJSON.cs:690
```

which indicates that even though its a switch (line 605) and the case is aJSON[i] is ',' it seems like for some reason, aJSON[i] happened to be null.

does any of you know why this could have happened?
also, there was not even a ',' digit in that part...

I did not change the script.
I did not add the SimpleJSONUnity.cs

Comment: I have little ambitions to parse all your code and possibly find a mistake ... what I can say already: SimpleJSON is not ment to be parsed character by character of the input string. It rather expects a valid JSON string as input and can return ceratin items like `var N = JSON.Parse(the_JSON_string);
var versionString = N["item"].Value;` you should rather focus on turning the string you receive into a valid JSON string than there should be no issues with it.

Comment: Hi

you are right. in fact, the problem was before the script when i got the HTTP answer and sent it to Deserialization without grabbing the body first.
after debugging the whole answer I released that.

Simple json has a ctx variable that initializes once reaching a { digit (1st in the json, not 1st in the HTTP call). that's why i was being thrown a null error 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was before the script when i got the HTTP answer and sent it to Deserialization without grabbing the body first.

after debugging the whole answer I released that. Simple json has a ctx variable that initializes once reaching a { digit (1st in the json, not 1st in the HTTP call).

that's why I was being thrown a null error